# Reset timer on firebase Job dispatcher

Tags: android, firebase

This is a simple question.  Creating a Firebase Job Dispatcher job with an interval means the job will commence in about that much time.  Is there a way, other than destroying and recreating the job, to simply reset the timer?

Comment: Can you tell us the reason why you want to reset the timer without destroying the job?

Comment: Mainly to cut down on code complexity. there's settings that can change the interval of the job as well as calls the job handles that are done on demand within the app, so I'd like to be able to reset the timer to avoid duplicate calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so there is any other way to schedule new job without destroyed current one.

That's perfect way to stop current and destroyed it and after schedule again when you want to schedule based on your time.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: everything I've looked at confirms this answer, so you get the bounty!